# Ban a User in a particular firebase firestore group chat for predefined time

Tags: flutter, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I am very new to coding. but i managed to build a group chat app using a low code platform called flutterflow. i managed to spend significant amount of time on it and was able to build a public group chat app except few functionalities. I am hoping to find help from here. for the following questions.

1. I have chat mods appointed on a group level. like if you create a group, you are a founder and you can assign mods to that perticular group chat. now i want these mods to be able to ban a user in that particular group chat.

I have tried created a subcollection in groups called "banned user" and created two feilds. one is "banned users" document reference to users. and another is "banned_till" to record a time stamp until the user gets banned.

Problem with this is when i ban a user twice, it creates two documents in the user reference with the same user. and two documents has different "banned_till" times. which one it is supposed to pick?

i tried to do this and put a conditional visibility to the chat that "if current time is less than or equal to  banned_till time" it wont let user type in the textfield to chat. but this is giving me gray screen.

I am very new to this. any help would be appreciated.

Comment: If a user is banned multiple times, you'll want to use the document with the latest `banned_till` value. You could also allow only a single document in `banned user` for each user by using the user ID as the ID of the document.

Comment: Hi, Thanks for the reply. I think It is being saved with user ID in the document reference of "banned_user". still it is creating another document for every user everytime he gets banned. im attaching screenshots of it in firestore database. [link](http://prntscr.com/u2Ocor8chU84)ss1 and [link](http://prntscr.com/CKaoWfvtPalX)ss2

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

there is specific way to do so. you have to set custom logic. like save all banned users in a firebase database object with thier max time and procced next.